# Cleaning up old TFS installations

Tags: tfs

After some in-place upgrades of TFS, program files now contains:

- Microsoft Team Foundation Server 11.0 (2,04 GB)
- Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0 (36,5 GB)
- Microsoft Team Foundation Server 15.0 (1,58 GB)  <--- current

The 36 GB from version 12 resides mostly in folders named *_tfs_data* in *TFSJobAgent* and *Web Services* folders.

Is it safe to remove these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's safe to remove them. That should all be data cached by previous installations, which is no longer used.